# Add together a time and a number to get a total

Tags: php, time

I have two times in two different formats that I need to add together:

1. A post time '12:30'
2. A user submitted number (to indicate a time duration) Ex: 1 = hour, 0.5 = 30 minutes

I need to add both together to get the total, Ex: 12:30 + 0.5 = 14:00.

I am stuck currently and am missing something simple, could anyone give me a pointer?

Code:

```
// Get Post Time
$post_date = strtotime(get_the_date('G:i'));
// Get User Submitted Number
$post_duration = strtotime($course_hours);
// Add Together
$output = $post_date + $post_duration;
// Output
echo 'Start Time: '.get_the_date('G:i') .' - ';
// Fail Here
echo 'End Time: '. date('G:i', $output);
```

Comment: `12:30 + 0.5 = 14:00` <- that's going to be a hard one to figure out ?

Comment: 0.5 is not a date or time or timestamp or anything of significance with respect to time. You'll need to break out some elementary math to convert 0.5 to 30 minutes yourself. PHP doesn't have a function for that.

Comment: That is my problem, somewhere there I have made a mistake. An example output with 0.5 from the user is: Start Time: 14:15 - End Time: 6:51

Comment: `strtotime($course_hours . ' hours');`

Comment: `function numberToMinutes($number){
    return $number * 0.6 * 100;
}`

Comment: @adeneo `bool(false)`

Comment: This `$post_duration = strtotime($course_hours);` will never work. If you want to do some math here read about [Date/Time extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) in php

Comment: Ok, thanks all. So I would need to convert the user number to minutes, then pass that to strtotime ?

Comment: try `echo date('G:i', strtotime("12:30 + 0.5 hours"));`

Comment: @Kamran `bool(false)`

Comment: @deceze i have modified and posted  it as answer. Please check if it is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$add = 0.5 * 60 ; // convert posted hours to minutes 
$post_time = "12:30";
echo $post_date = date('G:i',strtotime("+ $add minutes" , strtotime($post_time)));
```

Comment: This looks decent, just testing this now. Thank you.

Comment: From PHP about `strtotime`: _Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable. It is better to use DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() in PHP 5.3 and later, or DateTime::modify() in PHP 5.2._